# Insert copied data from XML file into Insert SQL query

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have a process in which all I manually copy/paste all the data from a .xml file and paste into an insert statement that puts the data into a single row on a sql table

Sample XML:

```
<Data_Export>
    <Header>
        <Sample_Data> This is the data string </sample_data>
    </Header>
</Data_Export>
```

Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo.table] ([XML])
VALUES ('<Data_Export>
             <Header>
                <Sample_Data> This is the data string </sample_data>
             </Header>
          </Data_Export>')
```

I'm looking for a way to automate this piece of the process- so that instead of manually copy/pasting the XML data I can have insert into the single SQL row as part of a SSIS or Data Factory process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directory and file name is known,

**Example**

```
Declare @XML xml; 
Select @XML = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\somedir\data.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x; 

INSERT INTO [dbo.table] ([XML]) Values ( @XML )
```